# Attach onmouseover() function to each href in all <a> anchor tags, if anchor tags have <img> child elements?

Tags: anchor, href, addeventlistener, onmouseover, queryselector

HTML code:

```
<p><div>
<a href="https://www.digi.com.my/chat-with-us">
<img src="">
</a></p><div>

<p><a href="https://unifi.com.my/support/contact-us"><img src="">
    </a></p>
  </div>

<p><a>Hey Man 
</a>
</p>

<div>
<p><a href="https://unifi.com.my/support/contact-us">Hey man
</a>
</p></div>
```

Javascript code:

```
let tar = document.querySelectorAll("a[href] > img[src]");

tar.forEach(tarG => {
tarG.addEventListener("mouseover", e => {
    const ahref = e.target.a[href];
  if (a[href]) location.assign(a[href]);
   });
});
```

First, I want to attach onmouseover() function to all href links in all  anchor tags with an  child tags, in an HTML page.

My intention is that the onmouseover() function only activates the href, when the mouse cursor moves over a anchor tag containing the img child tag. Otherwise, if there is no img child tag, the  onmouseover() function does not activate the href.

Where did my code go wrong? Thank you for all the helpful answers

Answer (score 0):

Replace your JavaScrip code with this:

```
const tars = document.querySelectorAll('a > img');

tars.forEach(tar => {
  const a = tar.parentNode;

  a.addEventListener('mouseover', /* Your mouseover handler goes here */);
});
```

Comment: "Your mouseover handler goes here "

May I see that code, please?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do on mouseover. You show me!

Comment: I want to be able to activate those anchor tags with img child elements. My onmouseover function:

```("mouseover", , e => {
                                                                                                                                 const a = e.target.a;
     
                                                                                                                                        if (a) location.assign(a);     
                                                                                                                                    });
}); ```

Comment: That's what I'm saying: We have no idea what "activate those anchor tags with img child elements" means. Further, you are using an identifier `location` without showing or telling us what it is. You are probably interested in `e.target.href`.

Answer (score -1):

sorry for vague answer. in your code you are adding event listener to img. you need to get parentnode of tar and then add event listener to it.

```js
//js
x = [].slice
    .call(document.querySelectorAll("img"))
    .filter((e) => e.parentNode.tagName == "A")
    .map((e) => e.parentNode);
console.log(x);
//jquery
y = $("a img").parent();
console.log(y.toArray());

//you can now add eventlisteners to x,y
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Does this mean I replace my entire code with yours, or add on your code to mine?

Comment: sorry for vague answer. in your code you are adding event listener to img. you need to get parentnode of tar and then add event listener to it

Answer (score -1):

```
const tars = document.querySelectorAll("a > img"); 
tars.forEach(tar => {                                                                                   
const a = tar.parentNode;`   

a.addEventListener("mouseover", e => {
    const ahref = e.target.tar;
   if (tar) location.assign(tar);     
   });
  });
```

like this, @Corey?